# If I train my rabbit to jump fences will she STILL stay in a two foot exercise pen?

Tags: behavior, training, rabbits, containment

I just watched [Rabbit Jumping: How to Get Started](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwazb0ds3a0) I have a couple of rabbits that are very trainable, but I take them a lot of places where I expect them to stay in 2 foot high exercise pens.  If I teach them to jump fences, will they start jumping out of the pen on their own?

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question in the comments of the video on YouTube and recieved an answer from Barbara Heidenreich that a rabbit will most likely not generalize jumping hurdles to jumping fences. As long as keep the pen a fun place to be and only teach the rabbit to jump hurdles she should not jump the pen.

Similar behavior is seen in horses that are trained to [jump obstacles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse_jumping_obstacles) the jumping of obstacles is not associated to the ability to jump the fence that marks the boundary of their pasture.